# Stored Procedure changes not reflecting case sensitivity in dacpac script

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

Suppose I have a stored procedure which as follows,

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTest](
    @ServiceId      INT,
    @ReturnMessage      VARCHAR(100) OUTPUT
)    
AS
IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Service WHERE ServiceID = @ServiceId)=0
BEGIN
    SET @ReturnMessage = 'available';
END
```

Once I doing the changing to any word by make it uppercase or lowercase, that change is not reflect in the database once I run the dacpac.

**EX:** If I change as `available` to uppercase

```
BEGIN
    SET @ReturnMessage = 'AVAILABLE';
END
```

The above change is not reflecting in the database. If I do the same thing and add some comment at the end of it as:

```
BEGIN
    SET @ReturnMessage = 'AVAILABLE'; --did a change
END
```

Above thing is reflecting in database without any issue. Why this happening, can anyone explain me.

Comment: By the way, `EXISTS(SELECT 1...)` is generally more efficient than `(SELECT COUNT...) = 0`

Comment: Note, if any value was passed to `@ReturnMessage` it won't be overwritten with anything. If you pass `AVAILABLE` and the row does not exist - `AVAILABLE` will be returned.

Comment: Could be it realizes that nothing but string literal has changed and DB uses CI (case insensitive) collation, so this change would have no effect on behavior (I've never tested such a case)

Comment: Seems like can't be overridden even for object names unless CS collation used https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b485d3c5-e3be-48cd-b1cd-ea031c29602e/refactor-rename-only-case-changes-are-ignored?forum=ssdt

Answer (score 3):

The below `/Publish` parameters will decide, how keyword casing & comment changes are considered as changes or not. You can see your settings in the DACPAC publish and accordingly make changes to the publish settings.

> /p:   IgnoreQuotedIdentifiers=(BOOLEAN 'True')
> /p:   IgnoreComments=(BOOLEAN)

[More information on Publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-publish?view=sql-server-ver15#parameters-for-the-publish-action)

Comment: @Venkataraman R As Ivan says this is not a keyword

Comment: @thomsan, ivan is right. updated my answer.

Comment: @VenkataramanR Can u please explain what  IgnoreQuotedIdentifiers is does?

Comment: @VenkataramanR and what is the difference of (BOOLEAN 'True') and (BOOLEAN)

Comment: @VenkataramanR I tried `IgnoreQuotedIdentifiers=false`, but not working for me

Comment: I'm afraid it does not seem to be any kind of _identifier_

Comment: @thomsan, also see if your database project settings for collation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/database-project-settings?view=sql-server-ver15